# Compute the correlation by looping through factor levels in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate, correlation

Here is the data structure in `R`:

```
library(MASS)
ns <- 10; nt <- 20
dat <- data.frame(
          Subj  = rep(c(paste0('S',1:ns), paste0('S',1:ns)), nt),
          F     = rep(c(rep('f1', ns), rep('f2',ns)), nt),
          T     = rep(paste0('t', 1:nt), each=2*ns),
          y     = c(mvrnorm(n=ns, mu=c(0, 0), Sigma=matrix(c(1,0.7,0.7,1), nrow=2,ncol=2)))
                  +rnorm(2*ns*nt, 0, 1) )
```

I want to compute the correlation of the variable `y` between the two levels (`f1` and `f2`) of the factor `F` separately for each level of the factor `Subj`. This should end up with 10 correlations in this example. One more condition is that the sequence for each of the two vectors in the correlation formula should be arranged in the same order per the levels of the factor `T`.

How to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `by` in base R.

```
subdat <- dat[order(dat$T), c("y", "F", "Subj")]
by(subdat, subdat$Subj, function(x) with(x, cor(y[F == "f1"], y[F == "f2"])))
```

Output

```
subdat$Subj: S1
[1] -0.03755675
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
subdat$Subj: S10
[1] -0.05481364
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
subdat$Subj: S2
[1] 0.2822211
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
subdat$Subj: S3
[1] 0.2671967
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
subdat$Subj: S4
[1] 0.1268404
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
subdat$Subj: S5
[1] 0.0374699
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
subdat$Subj: S6
[1] 0.5655247
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
subdat$Subj: S7
[1] 0.2141196
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
subdat$Subj: S8
[1] 0.250178
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
subdat$Subj: S9
[1] 0.1370734
```